# Run PDI jobs direct inside pentaho bi server 5.1 CE

Tags: pentaho

is it in principle possible to upload and run PDI jobs in bi server?

I have tried it, but always get this error in the user console:

> Sorry. We really did try. Something went wrong. Please try again or contact your administrator.

in conjunction with this log file error message:

> 2014/08/02 14:04:43 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: FromInputStream
>   14:04:43,384 ERROR [GeneratorStreamingOutput] Error generating content from content generator with id [viewer]

Could some give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe what have you done so far?

Comment: Yes, sure. I've uploaded the job- and transformation files via browser into BA server and then tried to open then.

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer: That does not work in the CE edition. That functionality is available only in the EE edition.

I'm not sure that's by design, so I think you should open an issue at jira.pentaho.com.

In the meantime, you can run PDI jobs in the biserver CE if you use xactions or CDA.