# Installation error : Sorry. We really did try. Something went wrong. Please try again or contact your administrator

Tags: java, linux, pentaho

First time I try to install Pentago by using [this link](http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.com/2014/01/installation-of-pentaho-bi-server-501.html).

I summarize that, so far what I done from the given link.

**PART- I JAVA (Open - JDK)- Installation**

To install `Java`,

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Open .bashrc file using an nano editor. And following lines are added at the mid of file. Becaues ther aren't mention the location need to be paste

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/
export JAVA_HOME
```

**PART- II Pentaho 5.0.1 CE installation**

```
mkdir /home/folder1/pentaho
cp //windowspath/biserver-ce-5.0.1-stable.zip /home/folder1/pentaho/
unzip file under  pentaho
./start-pentaho.sh
./stop-pentaho.sh
```

Then, finally I generate following link:

*http://ip.addr.of.server:8080/pentaho/*

[image: Web page.]

But it shows me an error. I need your help for get home page of Pentaho.

Linux OS version:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.5 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

**wget Error:**

```
--2019-09-24 08:17:20--  http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Business
Resolving sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)... 216.105.38.13
Connecting to sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)|216.105.38.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Business [following]
--2019-09-24 08:17:20--  https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Business
Connecting to sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)|216.105.38.13|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-09-24 08:17:21 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2019-09-24 08:17:21--  http://intelligence/
Resolving intelligence (intelligence)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `intelligence'
--2019-09-24 08:17:21--  http://server/5.0.1-stable/biserver-ce-5.0.1-stable.zip/
Resolving server (server)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `server'
```

I found [this link with same error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094888/run-pdi-jobs-direct-inside-pentaho-bi-server-5-1-ce) But not during installing. And [forums.pentaho](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/226571-Pentaho-Message-Sorry-Something-went-wrong/) is not opening with **502 Bad Gateway** error.

Note:

1. This is my step for install Pentaho.
2. I installed Java like reference link.
3. The zip is manually downloaded in Windows and moved to `/home/folder1/pentaho/`. Using `mount` command.

**Versions:**

Pentaho:

The file is `biserver-ce-5.0.1-stable.zip`. So version may be `5.0.1`.

Java:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222-ea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-ea-8u222-b05-1~12.04.1-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b05, mixed mode)
```

Comment: That is a rather old manual, but the basic process should be the same. What are the Pentaho and Java versions that you are using?

Comment: I have no idea about version, so far. Let me check same.

Comment: Pentaho version number should be in the zip file name. Running the command "java -version" should get you the version of the default Java installation. These are vital, since the newer Pentaho versions (7+ I think) need at least Java 8 64bit

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A web page alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Cyrus question has been updated.

Comment: @jww, are you OK with my updated question..? I added commands what was I ran.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a complete answer on how to do this, as the software version you're trying to run is so old it's hard to find the packages, likely to break other stuff on my machine and insecure as well.

*Before spending more time, you should really verify that you absolutely need this version and cannot use a newer one. The newer ones are a lot easier to install. Just verify/install Java, unzip and run start-pentaho.sh*

The way to get the old Pentaho to work is to really double check EVERY step.

1. It's very likely that **apt-get install openjdk7-xxx** fails because there are few repositories that still have it. Check again if the packages are installed correctly.
2. Double check that the path to the jdk is correct. Try to run java -version from that directory to verify the version. It must say "1.7.xx"
3. The **JAVA_HOME** is probably in your .bashrc, not that of the user pentaho. Check it. Even better, go and **hack the start-pentaho.sh script and set it there**, just before the actual call to start tomcat server.
4. CD to pentaho-server folder and run ./start-pentaho.sh Check the logging output to the console window and tomcat/logs/catalina.out for errors and try to solve them.
5. If the server manages to start up, go to the url and see what happens. Check the output in the console window.

Comment: Okay Cyrus, Thanks. Let me try this.